# Apps crash on Lumia 520

Tags: whatsapp, lumia-520

I am unable to open whatsapp. Whenever I try to open it, and opening any chat, the screen just goes back to the home. I tried restarting my phone and also reinstalling whatsapp but nothing works. I have tried soft reset and hard reset also but then also it is not working. Same thing happening with my instagram, uc browser and also the apps which are using through net...Can u please help me?

Comment: Where Whatsapp is instaled on phone or Micro Sd card?

Comment: Phone memory as system not allow to install on sd card

Comment: Please reply any1